# How to prove $A = (A \cap B) \cup (A - B)$ and show that $(A \cap B)$ and $(A - B)$ are non-intersecting.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I thought about starting with $A = (A \cap B) \cup (A)$ since $(A-B)$ is essentially saying only consider $A$. This would then lead me to proving $A = (A \cap B)$. However I'm completely stuck on how to prove they are non-intersecting.

Comment: $A-B$ is not saying only consider $A$, unless $A$ and $B$ are disjoint. $A-B$ is the set of all the elements of $A$ that are not in $B$

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 2):

HINT

You can use $A - B = A \cap B^C$

Comment: Thanks for the hint

Comment: @peakyblinders You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

By definition:

$A\cap B=\{x|x \in A \text { and }x\in B\}$

$A-B=\{x|x \in A \text { and } x \not \in B\} $

$C\cup D=\{x| x \in C \text { OR } x\in D\} $

So $(A\cap B)\cup (A-B)=$

$\{x|(x\in A \text { and }x\in B)\text { OR } (x\in A \text { and }x \not \in B)\}= $

$\{x|x \in A \text { and } x \text{ either is or isn't in } B\}=$

$\{x|x \in A \text { and nothing can be said about whther} x \text { is in }B\}= $

$\{x|x\in A\} =$

$A $.

===

Likewise

$(A\cap B)\cap (A-B)=$

$\{x|(x\in A\text{ and } x\in B)\text{ and } (x\in A \text { and }x\not \in B\} =$

$\{x|x \in A \text { and } x \text { is both in and not in }B\} $

There can't be any elements that are both in and not in a set.  So these do not intersect.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Very clear to understand

Answer (score 0):

Let $A,B \subset X$.

Using Bram28's hint:  $A - B = A \cap B^C$.

1) Distributive Law:

$(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B^C) = $

$A \cap (B \cup B^C) = A \cap X = A$ .

2) Associative and Commutative Law:

$(A \cap B) \cap (A \cap B^C) = $

$A \cap (B \cap B^C) = A \cap \emptyset = \emptyset$.

Comment: Thanks! Explanation was easy to follow

Comment: Quick question, why do we have to let A and B be subsets? X represents the universe?

Comment: @peakyblinders. X represents the universe. cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435647/universe-in-set-theory-and-category-theory. I just would feel better to start from somewhere , X, and consider operations of subsets A and B of X.